# How to show parsed data with SwiftUI?

Tags: api, parsing, swiftui

I'm trying to show in a view parsed data from an API using SwiftUI.

I'm fetching correctly the data using this code:

```
import UIKit

class APIController: ObservableObject {
    
    func apiCall() {
        
        // URL
        let url = URL(string: "https://geek-jokes.p.rapidapi.com/api?format=json")
        
        guard url != nil else {
            print("Error creating url object")
            return
        }
        
        // URL Rquest
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
        
        // Specify the header
        let headers = [
            "x-rapidapi-key": "d1363cbe66msh266920b6366eaacp1f87dfjsn050e3f8e58e2",
            "x-rapidapi-host": "geek-jokes.p.rapidapi.com"
        ]
        
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        
        //     Specify the body
        //        let jsonObject = [
        //            "sign": "Aries"
        //        ] as [String:Any]
        //
        //        do {
        //        let requestBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
        //
        //            request.httpBody = requestBody
        //        }
        //        catch {
        //            print("Error creating the data object from json")
        //        }
        
        // Set the request type
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        // Get the URLSession
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        // Create the data task
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            // Check for errors
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                
                //          Try to parse out the JSON data
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                do {
                    let jokesData = try decoder.decode(JokesData.self, from: data!)
                    
                    print(jokesData)
                }
                catch {
                    print("Error in JSON parsing")
                }
                
                //             Try to print out the JSON data
                //                do {
                //                    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                //                    print(dictionary)
                //
                //                }
                //                catch {
                //                    print("Error parsing response data")
                //                }
                
            }
        }
        
        // Fire off the data task
        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

Then I'm not sure if the data is correctly imported in JokesData.swift

```
import foundation

struct JokesData: Codable {

    var joke:String = ""

}
```

And when I try to load the data in JokesView.swift, nothing appear :(

```
import SwiftUI

struct JokesView: View {

    var jokesData: JokesData

    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        Text(jokesData.joke)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

If someone has an idea of what I did wrong, it would be very helpful.

Comment: You have to put the decoding code into a `Observable` class, this can be `ViewRouter` and @Publish `jokesData`

Comment: Place your parsing code in the ViewRouter as you are observing this in JokesView.  ViewRouter should have the Published property jokesData or may be joke if interested to update joke only and access it in JokesView as viewRouter.jokesData.joke

Comment: @vadian Damn, I tried many things but nothing seems to work. By decoding code you mean the struct JokesData?

Comment: @Apoorv by parsing code you mean the struct JokesData?

Comment: Mostly I mean the `dataTask / JSONDecoder` stuff, the struct can be anywhere.

Comment: @vadian I added the dataTask / JSONDecoder in a observable class, but the issue is that dataTask / JSONDecoder (and other stuff) are in a func apiCall (that is useful to trigger the code from other views), and it seems that I can't Published var jokesData "Cannot reference invalid declaration 'data'"

Comment: I meant to say create & populate  @Published var jokesData: JokesData in ViewRouter. Now, whenever it changes the view update itself.

Comment: @Apoorv added Published var jokesData: JokesData in ViewRouter and Xcode returns "Class 'ViewRouter' has no initializers" and when I try to fix it by giving a string default value it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In `APIController` add a property

  ```
  @Published var jokesData = JokesData()
  ```
- Replace the `do - catch` block in the completion handler with

  ```
    do {
        let jokesData = try decoder.decode(JokesData.self, from: data!)

        print(jokesData)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.jokesData = jokesData
        }

    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
  ```

  it assigns the received data to the publishing `jokesData` property.
- In the view create a `@StateObject` of the controller, in the `onAppear` modifier load the data, the view will be updated automatically.

  ```
  import SwiftUI

  struct JokesView: View {

      @StateObject var apiController = APIController()

      var body: some View {
          Text(apiController.jokesData.joke)
              .foregroundColor(.black)
              .onAppear() {
                  apiController.apiCall()
              }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: It works, thanks so much @vadian! Really appreciated. Holy DispatchQueue..