# Wait for request to be precessed for displaying information

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, request

I want to make a Swift (5.4.6) app to display information about cryptos. For this I need to call a server to get the information I want to display. However my application don't wait for the data to be processed so I get an error for wanting to display a nil.

Here is my code for the call to the server :

```
        
        var cryptos = Cryptos(cryptos: nil)
        
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    cryptos = try decoder.decode(Cryptos.self, from: data!)
                    print(cryptos.cryptos![6].name)
                }
                catch {
                    print("Impossible de convertir les données reçues")
                }
            }
        }
            dataTask.resume()
        return cryptos
    }
```

Here are the struct I want to decode the json into :

```
struct Crypto: Codable {
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
    let price: Float
    let totalSupply: Float
    let marketCap: Float
    let change24h: Float
}

struct Cryptos: Codable {
    let cryptos: [Crypto]?
}
```

Finally here is the code in my view :

```
var lesCryptos = Cryptos()

struct CryptoList: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationView {
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: getAllCryptosInfos)
    }
    
}

func getAllCryptosInfos() {
    lesCryptos = Worker().getAllCryptosInfos()
    print(lesCryptos.cryptos![7].name)
}
```

The error appears when I want to print the name ("lesCryptos.cryptos!" is nil)

Also here is a sample of the JSON i get :

```
{
  "cryptos": [
    {
      "name":"Bitcoin",
      "symbol":"BTC",
      "price":36301.41347043701,
      "totalSupply":18728856,
      "marketCap":679883945484.275,
      "change24h":0.36443243
    },
    {
      "name":"Ethereum",
      "symbol":"ETH",
      "price":2784.5450982190573,
      "totalSupply":116189845.499,"marketCap":323535864747.07007,
      "change24h":3.46116544
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is SwiftUI, there’s no need to wait.  *Publish* `cryptos`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67858815/how-to-show-parsed-data-with-swiftui#comment119947147_67858815) is a very similar question I answered just yesterday.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am very new to the swift world, do you have any examples?

Comment: You can't return from an async method. And the way you do it, the return executes before the closure has finished. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31264556/2227743) (and there's plenty of other ones on the site). Start by studying this then you will be able to adapt to your own case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your responses, however I managed to resolve my problem using completionHandler. Here is the link to the question and answers that helped me : [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your `struct` to a `class` and setup default values so that there is no `nil` values to cause crashes.

```
class Crypto: Codable {
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
    let price: Float
    let totalSupply: Float
    let marketCap: Float
    let change24h: Float

    init() {
        name = ""
        symbol = ""
        price = 0.0
        totalSupply = 0.0
        marketCap = 0.0
        change24h: 0.0
    }
}
```

In my example, notice that the `init()` constructor takes in no values. This allows me to create an object `Crypto()` without passing any values. This means that my object will have those default values, which is useful in your case because you're crashing from `nil` values.

```
struct ExampleView: View {
     @State var someCrypto = Crypto()

     var body: some View {
         Text("\(someCrypto.name)"
              .onAppear(
                   someCrypto.name = "Example"
              )
     }
}
```

In this example I'm using my default constructor for my `Crypto` object. That ensures that my view can display the name `""` given by `someCrypto.name`. Then I use `onAppear` to simulate fetching of your data from the API. You will notice that the view updates automatically. This is because of the `@State` object which essentially tells the view to listen for any changes, and those changes are `two-way`. While in this context a `Text()` is not actually going to use it `two-way` a `TextField()` would.

Additional reading and studying should be looked up for `@State` `@ObservedObject` `@ObservableObject` and `@Published` which will help you get off your feet and use SwiftUI much more responsively.